# How to check if an element is of an unknown type when browser does not implement HTMLUnknownElement

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to know from elements in the DOM while parsing them if they are unknown elements or not.  Typically thus far I've done:

```
element instanceof HTMLUnknownElement
```

This is fine for the most part, but it turns out that not all browsers has the HTMLUnknownType. How can I then identify wether or not the element is in fact a known element type or not.

Comment: Uff, sure the problem of browser compatiblity,... Have u tryed to print out the instance on other browsers?

Comment: According to [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement), `HTMLUnknownElement` is supported in all browsers ?

Comment: It really is kinda weird, saw the same thing on MDN - but trying in the console of Safari 5.1.7 on Windows, there is no type called HTMLUnknownElement.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use either Modernizer or something like this snippet?

```
var test_canvas = document.createElement("canvas") //try and create sample canvas element
var canvascheck=(test_canvas.getContext)? true : false //check if object supports getContext() method, a method of the canvas element
alert(canvascheck) //alerts true if browser supports canvas element
```

Taken from 
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/createelementcheck.shtml

http://modernizr.com/

Comment: The problem is more that I have custom elements and want to clientside swap these out with the actual DOM that represent that custom element - custom template / view engine. The elements does not exist in the HTML vocabulary and I just need to be able to differentiate these.

Comment: Could you add a property (called custom) to the element and then check if that property exists/is true ?

Comment: The elements are loaded from disk, parsed and then traversed before added to the DOM - problem is; at this point I need to know what kind of elements I'm dealing with.